# Changing existing String and Factor type column with NAs to Ordered Factor

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that has a column which was imported as `string` by default. 
The column `age_range` looks like this:

```
< 1 yr
10+ yrs
5-10 yrs
3-5 yrs
10+ yrs
NA
1-2 yrs
1 yr
NA
3-5 yrs
...
```

The values of that column was

```
c(NA (or blank), '< 1 yr', '1-2 yrs', '3-5 yrs', '5-10 yrs', '10+ yrs')
```

Now I want to replace the blanks as `string` 'NA' and then convert the column type to `ordered factor` using the same order above.

When I go to another machine, I have this column as (unordered) `factor` by default (as a newbie to R, I don't know how it happened, so bear with me).

How do I convert it to same, coming from both as `string` and `factor` type?

Comment: `df$col[is.na(df$col) | trimws(df$col) == ""] <- "NA" ; df$col = factor(df$col, levels = "your list")`

Comment: always share a sample of your data and the expected output from that sample in your questions for us to work on!

Comment: Might be worth adding `ordered=TRUE` to the factor call since that's important. And to your statement about the data being read in as factors on another machine, it's likely due to a difference in functions used. Some functions, like `read.csv` automatically convert strings to functions while some functions, like `readr::read_csv`, don't.